# What is the proper way to programmatically close a WinForms application after a certain time?

Tags: c#, winforms

I start my form in the usual way:

```
Application.Run(new MainForm());
```

I want it to open and run until a certain time, then close.  I've tried the following but to no avail:

(1) In the Main method (were the Application.Run() statement is), I enter the following AFTER Application.Run()

```
while (DateTime.Now < Configs.EndService) { }
```

RESULT:  It never gets hit.

(2) BEFORE Application.Run() I start a new Background Thread:

```
        var thread = new Thread(() => EndServiceThread()) { IsBackground = true };
        thread.Start();
```

where EndServiceThread is:

```
    public static void EndServiceThread()
    {
        while (DateTime.Now < Configs.EndService) { }
        Environment.Exit(0);
    }
```

RESULT:  vshost32.exe has stopped working crash.

(3) In MainForm Tick Event:

```
        if (DateTime.Now > Configs.EndService)
        {
            this.Close();
            //Environment.Exit(0);
        }
```

RESULT:  vshost32.exe has stopped working crash.

What is the proper way to achieve my goal?  Again, I want to launch the Form, have it open & running until a certain time (Configs.EndService), then close.

Thank you,
Ben.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a [Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx), and have it close the program in its event handler.

Say you want the application to shut down after 10 minutes. You initialize the timer with a period of 60,000 milliseconds. Your event handler becomes:

```
void TimerTick(object sender)
{
    this.Close();
}
```

If you want it to close at a specific date and time, you can have the timer tick once per second, and check `DateTime.Now` against the desired end time.

This will work because the `TimerTick` will execute on the UI thread. The problem with your separate thread idea was that `Form.Close` was called on a background thread, *not* the UI thread. That throws an exception. When you interact with UI elements, it has to be on the UI thread.

Your background thread idea probably would work if you called `Form.Invoke` to execute the `Close`.

You could also create a `WaitableTimer` object and set its event for the specific time. The Framework doesn't have a `WaitableTimer`, but one is available. See the article [Waitable Timers in .NET with C#](http://www.devsource.com/c/a/Languages/Waitable-Timers-in-NET-CSharp/). Code is available at http://www.mischel.com/pubs/waitabletimer.zip

If you use the `WaitableTimer`, be advised that the callback executes on a background thread. You'll have to `Invoke` to synchronize with the UI thread:

```
this.Invoke((MethodInvoker) delegate { this.Close(); });
```

Comment: @Grant: Yes, place the timer on the main form. Set its `Enabled` property to `True`, and its interval to whatever time check interval you want (1 second, 10 minutes, whatever).

Answer (score 4):

How about something like this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private static Timer _timer = new Timer();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _timer.Tick += _timer_Tick;
        _timer.Interval = 5000; // 5 seconds
        _timer.Start();            
    }

    void _timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Exit the App here ....
        Application.Exit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there "ServiceEnded" event? If yes close your form when your service ended.

Comment: the guy who asked the question needs to provide some more code to get better answer. I don't think closing the application with timer is good.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the `System.Threading.Timer` you can use the `DueTime` to set the first time it fires as the time you want to close your application

```
new System.Threading.Timer((o) => Application.Exit(), null, (Configs.EndService - DateTime.Now), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0));
Application.Run(new Form1());
```

Comment: Are you sure that it's safe to call `Application.Exit` from a background thread? In addition, this will fail if the system clock changes (Daylight Saving Time change, for example) while the program is running.

Comment: Application.Exit seems to be fine on a background thread (I tested this before posting), The close time is determined when the timer is created so changing the clock wont change the time the Timer fires

Comment: "The close time is determined when the timer is created." That's not true at all. The *amount of time to wait* is determined at creation time. If you started the program at midnight and wanted to close the program at 4:00 AM, this would wait 4 hours. But on "spring ahead" day, it would be 5:00 AM before the timer ticked. And on "fall back" day, the timer would tick at 3:00 AM. If the system clock changes, any time interval based on the previous value is invalid.

Comment: sorry I had no Idea OP wanted to factor in Daylight savings times, This code will simply(like you said) wait "x" amout of time before firing, if you need daylight saving support a running tick would be a better option. like your answer