# Clarity on 'Configs.EndService' in this stackoverflow answer I found

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, timer

Forum.

I found the following System.Threading.Timer answer/example on another stackoverflow question and I like it enough to try and use it:

```
new System.Threading.Timer((o) => Application.Exit(), null, (Configs.EndService - DateTime.Now), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0));
Application.Run(new Form1());
```

Regarding the 'Configs.EndService' variable, what is that, where would it be stored/located, and how?

I would comment on the original answer (located here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15491074/2272357) but I don't have enough reputation to do so.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be a DateTime variable, when the OP wanted the time to end. Store it wherever makes sense for your application.

This is just as valid:

```
var endTime = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(5);
new System.Threading.Timer((o) => Application.Exit(), null, (endTime - DateTime.Now), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0));
Application.Run(new Form1());
```