# c# How to exit from an application .exit() ExitThread() dont seem to work

Tags: exit, applicationcontext

I have a very simple application which launches another class which contains a tray nottification

```
    class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        // Once it successfuly connects with the WCF , we can start the 
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new AgentTray());
        Application.Exit();
```

here the code for the second class

public class AgentTray : ApplicationContext , IWcfServiceCallback
    {

```
    public AgentTray()
    {
        ......
        this.ExitThread();
        Application.Exit();
```

I run it in debug mode and I see that from AgentTray the two Exit commands are executed but the application still keeps running. In fact I put a breakpoint in the Application.Exit in the main method and the execution flow never reach that point.

Any idea what might be happening?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15490915/what-is-the-proper-way-to-programmatically-close-a-winforms-application-after-a

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the proper way to programmatically close a WinForms application after a certain time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15490915/what-is-the-proper-way-to-programmatically-close-a-winforms-application-after-a)